# Where to run component specific sagas?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

In my project we are currently running application wide sagas in store component specific sagas in each component, like this:

```
public componentDidMount() {
    sagaMiddleware.run(componentSpecificSagas);
}
```

But this means that components using sagas will always have application logic in them, even if they could otherwise be reusable ui components.

What is best practice for running component specific sagas? Should they perhaps just be run in store? Should they perhaps be run in the connector?

Comment: Why are you running saga middleware in separate components? If the root saga is run in the root component, then all the sagas run, and the rest of the component tree is decoupled from saga logic.

Comment: I think that sound like a good idea. I am tinkering with converting to that right now. The reason sagas are ran in components was that the guy who built it didn't want to setup event listeners for things until they were needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a root-level saga composed of your application-logic sagas:

```
function* rootSaga() {
    yield spawn(saga1)
    yield spawn(saga2)
    // ...
}
```

The run the saga at the root component. [Official redux-saga example](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/examples/real-world/index.js):

```
store.runSaga(rootSaga)

render(
    <Root
        //...
    />,
    //...
)
```

Then the rest of the component tree has no saga logic.